# vim path completion in command mode

Tags: vim, autocomplete

In vim, If you hit `:e <tab><tab>`, vim complete some path.

However, I want to open `a/b/c/d.cpp`, I stroke `:e <tab><tab>` and find `AA`.

I want to find subdirectory of `AA`. Alternatively, I hit `/` key.

example `:e AA//BB//CC//DD.cpp`

Are there another good way? In summary, I want to know complete path for subdirectory in command `:e`.

Comment: You mean something like `:e **/DD.cpp<tab>` ?

Comment: No, I want to just explore directories hierarchyically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer is based on the assumption you want the path for picking out the correct file for editing.

May I suggest to use `:find` after setting the path properly. This will save extra lot of typing.

You can start by setting `:set path+=**`(this will search sub-dirs as well). Now you can simply do

```
:find d.cpp
```

vim will do the rest for you. It will find out the path to `d.cpp` and open it.
What is nice about it is it allows to use wildcard, for example, as `:find d.*` or `:find *.cpp`.

If you don't want to use `find` and continue with `edit`, May be it will be useful to `:set wildmenu`. This will show all available options that you can iterate with <kbd>tab</kbd>

Comment: when I don't remember goal file, I want to just explore. For example <tab><tab><tab><CR><tab><CR><tab><CR>.

Comment: set wildmenu will help

Comment: Thanks to dlmeetei. I finally found what I want. <DOWN>

Answer (score 4):

Command-line completion lets you use wildcards.

The basic `*` means "any character":

```
:e *<Tab>          " similar to plain <Tab>
:e foo*<Tab>       " completes only files starting with 'foo'
```

The fancier `**` means "any subdirectory":

```
:e **/<Tab>        " completes every file under every subdirectory
                   " of the current working directory
:e **/*foo<Tab>    " completes every file ending with 'foo' under every subdirectory
                   " of the current working directory
```

See `:help file-searching`.

By the way, it's "command-line mode". "Command mode" is just another name for "normal mode".